# How to make menu and submenus recursively in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I want to make recursively and dynamic function for rendering navigation menu and submenus

I have JSON array of object where every object is menu item and menu item can have submenus and also submenu to have subsubmenus....I think you understand my logic.

Currently every object have title and submenus object optionally.

JSON object

```
[
{
    title: "menu 1"
    submenus: [
        {
            title: "sub menu1"
        },
        {
            title: "sub menu2"
            submenus: [
                {
                    title: "subsub menu1"
                    submenus: [
                        {
                            title: "susubsub menu1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'subsub menu2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    title: "menu 2"
}]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please add said JSON.

Comment: @JackBashford I added JSON array

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your best attempt  at solving the problem at hand so people can actually help you improve your solution

Comment: I tried something but I realized I have no idea how to this. That's why I'm searching for solution

Answer (score 2):

There are several JavaScript libraries that can produce dynamic menus with all kinds of visual aids. But if you implement it yourself, you would use these ingredients:

- A container HTML element in which the menu should be placed.
- A JavaScript recursive function to create the DOM elements for the menu and place them in the container element
- Click handlers which toggle the visibility of the submenus through styles
- CSS to give the menus some visual clues, and provide styles that show or hide the submenus

For example:

```js
function populateMenu(container, menu) {
    if (!menu || !menu.length) return;
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (const {title, submenus} of menu) {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = title;
        li.className = "leaf";       
        if (submenus) {
            populateMenu(li, submenus);
            li.className = "collapsed";       
            li.addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
                if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
                e.target.classList.toggle("expanded");
                e.target.classList.toggle("collapsed");
            });
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    container.appendChild(ul);
}

// Example menu definititon:
const menu = [{ title: "menu 1", submenus: [{ title: "sub menu1" }, { title: "sub menu2", submenus: [{ title: "subsub menu1", submenus: [{ title: "susubsub menu1"}]}, { title: "subsub menu2" }]}]}, { title: "menu 2" }];
// Provide the DOM element where the menu should be inserted:
populateMenu(document.getElementById("menu"), menu);
```

```css
li.collapsed > ul { display: none }
ul { cursor: pointer }
li.collapsed, li.expanded, li.leaf {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-indent: -2em;
}
li.expanded:before { content: '−  ' }
li.collapsed:before { content: '+  ' }
li.leaf:before { content: '○  ' }
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Comment: What's the "true" for in the statement "populateMenu(li, submenus, true);" ?

Comment: @Gus, nothing, it was a remnant of a test I think (3 years ago). Removed.

Answer (score 2):

Traverse nth level nested array list and code your logic in recursive function as per requirement.

I implemented this code for generating a menu list for a context menu of PrimeNG.

JSON data -

```
    [
      {
        "TITLE": "parent1",
        "SUBMENU": [
          {
            "SUBMENU": [
              {
                "SUBMENU": [
                  {
                    "TITLE": "Child 1"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "SUBMENU": [
                  {
                    "TITLE": "Child 3"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "SUBMENU": [
                  {
                    "SUBMENU": [
                      {
                        "TITLE": "Child 4"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "SUBMENU": [

                    ]
                  }
                ],

              },
              {
                "SUBMENU": [
                  {
                    "SUBMENU": [

                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],

          }
        ],

      },
      {
        "TITLE": "parent2",
        "SUBMENU": [
          {
            "TITLE": "Child 4"
          }
        ],

      }
    ]
```

JAVASCRIPT / Typescript Code -

```
traveRecusrivelist(object: any[]): any[] {
    if (object) {
      let newList: any[] = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        if (object[i].ITEMS && object[i].ITEMS.length > 0) {
            // TODO : code you logic here
           // create your own object and push in the newList array
          let returnedList = this.traveRecusrivelist(object[i].ITEMS);
          // Example : PrimeNG MenuItem creation
          // newList.push({ label: object[i].TITLE, items: returnedList, command: (event) => { } });
          newList.push(returnedList);
        }
        else {
            // TODO : code you logic here
           // example : PrimeNG menuItem 
           // newList.push({ label: object[i].TITLE, command: (event) => { } });
           // create your own object and push in the newList array
              newList.push(object[i]);
        }
      }
      return newList;
    }
  }

let list: any[] = [];
list = this.traveRecusrivelist(object);
console.log(list);
```

Comment: I like too, to run on recursion that way

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
  var a = {
  "menu1": {
     title: "menu1"
   },
   "menu2": {
     title: "menu2",
     submenu: {
       "menu3" : {
          title : "menu3"
        },
       "menu4": {
         title: "menu4",
         submenu: {
          "menu5": {
           title: "menu5"
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
 }



 function printMenu(menu){
     if(!menu) return "";

     var str = "";
     for(var i in menu)
     {
         if(menu[i].submenu)
            str+= "<li>"+menu[i].title+"<ul>"+printMenu(menu[i].submenu)+"</ul></li>";
         else
            str+= "<li>"+menu[i].title+"</li>";
     }
     return str;
 };

printMenu(a); // "<li>menu1</li><li>menu2<ul><li>menu3</li><li>menu4<ul><li>menu5</li></ul></li></ul></li>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on how to use recursion to go inside every single menu and submenu in your JSON :

```js
var myJson ='[{"title": "menu 1", "submenus": ['+
        '{"title": "sub menu1"},'+
        ' {"title": "sub menu2", "submenus": ['+
              ' {"title": "subsub menu1", "submenus": [{"title": "susubsub menu1"}]},'+
                ' {"title": "subsub menu2"}'+
            ']}]},'+
'{"title": "menu 2"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(myJson);

function recursive(object){
  if(object){
    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
      console.log(object[i].title);
        recursive(object[i].submenus);
    }
  }
}
recursive(obj);
```